# How to Reload the fragment from another fragment inside the viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

now iam having a view pager inside the activity. ViewPager have two fragments. Now i want to reload the fragment while swiping or it gets moved from one fragment to another by using objViewPager.setcurrentitem(0) or objViewPager.setcurrentitem(0). Please help... what i want is i want to refresh the second or first fragment while moved from first to second or second to first fragment respectively.. I have gone through many searches but all told fragment communication alone but not inside the view pager.....please suggest me ideas .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can understand from the question you want to make changes in the fragments when the user swipes right ? Basically you can just make an interface in the activity and implement it in the fragments.Call this interface in the ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener.(Where the above answer suggested).

Something like this . In the Activity,

```
public interface FragmentInterface{
    void Fragmentbecamevisible();
}
```

and call the function in the ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int i) {
        //do the setselectednavigationitem
        FragmentInterface frag=(FragmentInterface)mAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, arg0);
            if(frag!=null)
            {
                frag.Fragmentbecamevisible();
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

    }
});
```

So the interface function is called each time the fragments are switched or whenever swipe function occurs.
In the fragments just implement the interface , and in the Fragmentbecamevisible() function ,make all the changes you want to refresh the fragment.

```
public class Statistics_Fragment extends Fragment implements FragmentInterface
{   
@Override
public void Fragmentbecamevisible() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Make changes to your fragment.Each time the user navigates to this fragment .thhis function gets called


}
```

Hope this helps .
Feel free to make changes.

Comment: @Aswin Narayanan what is arg0 here

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use OnPageChangeListener.

```
 mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
           if (i == 2)
             // do your stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });
```

or you can refresh your fragment in onResume();
So each time you change back, onResume will be called.

Comment: yes oke but how to reload the fragment using that listener from its oncreate() method????

Comment: a dirty way to set PagerAdapter to ViewPager view again.

Comment: i think overridding the public int getItemPosition (Object object) by returning POSITION_NONE may do that